# Symfony3 How to create property to entity and use it in QueryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I'm building search function in a website of posts so I need a query to return all the results that matches certain criteria. It works with the title of the post but not with the description of the post, because the description is stored in the DB with HTML tags, and I need to strip these tags before search. It's really easy with PHP and the strip_tags() function, but I cannot do this inside the QueryBuilder.

So I want to create a new property to the entity that strips this tags and then search in DB with:

- In The Entity:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $full_description;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $question_description = strip_tags($this->getQuestionDescription());
        $problem_description = strip_tags($this->getProblemDescription());
        $this->full_description = $question_description . " " . $problem_description;
    }
```

- In Repository:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
    ->andWhere('UPPER(post.full_description) LIKE UPPER(:search_string)')
    ->setParameter('search_string',"%".$search_string."%")
```

Is there any way to do this?

pd.: Sorry for my english

Comment: you need two fields in DB: description_html and descctription_strip_tags

Comment: @TsV so there is no other way in Doctrine? Like using virtual properties ?